# Deploying Enterprise Archive into weblogic 10.3.4.0 application server

Tags: spring, hibernate, weblogic

I am trying to deploy enterprise archive into web-logic application server. This ear contains two modules. web service module and web application module.

This application was previously running on Apache tomcat server and now i am migrating to web-logic application server.

I am getting following error when deploying to the web-logic application server. Below exception.

For web service and web application, I am using Hibernate and Spring frameworks. Following are the dependencies of web service

```
[INFO]
[INFO] Building WebServiceModule Maven Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ MavenWebAppModule ---
[INFO] com.packt.maven:MavenWebAppModule:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- com.packt.maven:BusinessLogicModule:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] | +- com.packet.maven:DataPersistanceModule:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] | \- com.packt.maven:DataModelModule:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.packt.maven:WebServiceClientModule:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.struts:struts2-core:jar:2.1.8:compile
[INFO] | +- com.opensymphony:xwork-core:jar:2.1.6:compile
[INFO] | | \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:2.5.6:compile
[INFO] | +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.15:compile
[INFO] | +- ognl:ognl:jar:2.7.3:compile
[INFO] | +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] | \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.struts:struts2-spring-plugin:jar:2.1.8:compile
[INFO] | +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:2.5.6:compile
[INFO] | +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.6:compile
[INFO] | \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:2.5.6:compile
[INFO] | \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:provided (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] +- javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.1.GA:compile
[INFO] +- com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring:jar:2.5.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:2.5.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.7.ga:compile
[INFO] | +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] | +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B:compile
[INFO] | \- asm:asm-attrs:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] +- asm:asm:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO] +- javax.xml.soap:saaj-api:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] | \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] | \- org.jvnet:mimepull:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] \- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO]
```

Following are the dependencies of maven web app module

```
[INFO]
[INFO] Building MavenWebAppModule Maven Webapp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:tree (default-cli) @ WebServiceModule ---
[INFO] com.packt.maven:WebServiceModule:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring:jar:2.5.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:2.5.6:compile
[INFO] | +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:2.5.6:compile
[INFO] | +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:2.5.6:compile
[INFO] | | \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] | \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:2.5.6:compile
[INFO] +- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:provided (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] +- javax:javaee-api:jar:6.0:provided
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:test (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] +- com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate:jar:3.2.7.ga:compile
[INFO] | +- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] | +- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.0.1B:compile
[INFO] | \- asm:asm-attrs:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-rt:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] | +- javax.xml.ws:jaxws-api:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO] | | +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] | | \- org.glassfish:javax.annotation:jar:3.1-b35:compile
[INFO] | +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.3-1:compile
[INFO] | +- com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:jar:1.3.8:compile
[INFO] | +- com.sun.xml.stream.buffer:streambuffer:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] | +- org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO] | | \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] | +- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] | | \- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] | +- com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal:resolver:jar:20050927:compile
[INFO] | +- org.jvnet:mimepull:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO] | +- com.sun.xml.ws:policy:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] | | +- com.sun.xml.txw2:txw2:jar:20090102:compile
[INFO] | | \- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] | +- org.glassfish.gmbal:gmbal-api-only:jar:3.1.0-b001:compile
[INFO] | | \- org.glassfish.external:management-api:jar:3.0.0-b012:compile
[INFO] | \- org.glassfish.ha:ha-api:jar:3.1.8:compile
[INFO] +- asm:asm:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO] \- org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons.spring:jaxws-spring:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:jar:2.7:compile
[INFO] +- javax.jws:jsr181-api:jar:1.0-MR1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.xml.soap:saaj-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.sun.xml.stream:sjsxp:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]
```

In my weblogic application configuration i have provided following configuration to load java from my applications first. Could anybody help me on this issue. Thanks in advance for anyhelp

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-application
xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.0/weblogic-application.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_5.xsd">
<!--weblogic-version:10.3.1 -->
<wls:application-param>
<wls:param-name>webapp.encoding.default</wls:param-name>
<wls:param-value>UTF-8</wls:param-value>
</wls:application-param>

<wls:prefer-application-packages>
<wls:package-name>antlr.*</wls:package-name>
</wls:prefer-application-packages>
</wls:weblogic-application>
```

Exception.......

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.SpringBinding#0' defined in ServletContext resourcepring/config/SpringBeans.xml]: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService] while setting bean property 'service'; nested exceramework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.Linkageaint violation: when resolving field "DATETIME" the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) of the referring class, javax/xml/datatype/Datahe class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for the field's resolved type, javax/xml/namespace/QName, have different Class objects for that type
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:122)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1245)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1010)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:472)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1872)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3153)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1508)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:636)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205)
at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:58)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:528)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exceptiogeError: loader constraint violation: when resolving field "DATETIME" the class loader (instance of weblogic/utils/classloaders/ChangeAwareClassLoader) of the referring class, jtatypeConstants, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for the field's resolved type, javax/xml/namespace/QName, have different Class objects for that type
```

Comment: Sounds like there are duplicate classes somewhere in your path that conflict. Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638191/jboss-5-classloader-and-multiple-class-instances or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247662/xpath-class-resolution-in-jboss5 will help